# I successfully ran Product-> Archive but it doesn't show up in Organizer->Archive

Tags: iphone, xcode4.2

I'm trying to submit an application to the app store and I've come to the step where I'm building the application for archiving, which from my understanding I'm then supposed to be able to submit to the app store through [xcode](/questions/tagged/xcode).

It appears that the application is nowhere to be fund. I click `Product -> Archive` it says "Build succeeded", but then once I go into the Organizer and click archive there is no file there.

My Archive scheme has the checkbox *"Reveal Archive in Organizer"* checked.

Any ideas on what can be wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out my Archive scheme was set for release rather than distribution. Once I changed that the Organizer popped up when I bult it.